# persist Vs. continue

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, synonyms

Are in the following contexts '**continue**' and '**persist**' can be interchanged?

> He wants to **persist / continue** in his way.
>
> We should **persist /continue** in out treatment with antibiotics.
>
> People don't like to **persist /continue** suffering their pain.
>
> You should turn right and then **persist /continue** straight and
>   you'll see the destination on your right.
>
> She **persists / continues** to get a budget from her country.

Answer (score 1):

**To persist** is to continue despite contrary force or contrary pressure of some kind, such as recommendations, advice, setbacks, or "roadblocks".

**To continue** is merely to not abandon a course of action or behavior.

> If you persist in this behavior despite all the warnings you have received, you are likely to end up in juvenile prison.

**Continue**, since it is more general, can be used in place of **persist**, but **persist**, because it has the added notion of "despite contrary pressure" or "against advice" or whatever the opposing "force" may be, cannot always be substituted for **continue**:

> She *persists* <sup>NO</sup> to receive emails from a prince with 50 million dollars.

P.S. As a corollary, the action must be something she *does*, not something that happens to her.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1^). So basically I can use 'persist' in all of my examples if I want to convey presence of contrary.  Isn't it?

Comment: "contrary" very broadly construed. It only has to be something which might not be advisable to make *persist* possible. There doesn't have to be active opposition. The action need only run counter to social mores or the dictates of common sense, for example, or counter to some other nebulous principle: *He persisted in trying to pick the lock long after I would have given up.*